# Can i read a django file object straight into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I want to load a simple \t separated file into a pandas dataframe that I have loaded using django:

views.py

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')

        for f in files:
             df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Whats your problem?